# How to set cookies in Spark Java being deployed in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spark-java

Recently I started using Spark Java Framework (2.7.2) to create a lightweight web application. One of its requirements is that the application must be deployed to an Apache Tomcat Server 8.5.

I've managed to set things going, but I have not been able to set any custom cookie.

I have used the following method but none worked.

```
response.cookie("my_cookie", "value");
response.cookie("/path", "my_cookie", "value", -1, false, true);
```

It seems like tomcat is setting correctly the JSESSIONID cookie but I have no control over this cookie generation and I would like to generate a random and unique cookie, in order to be used for user authorization.

EDIT:

The control flow for setting the cookie is this

```
// In the main application
before("/*", AccessController.setSession);


// Method for setting an existing session
public static Filter setSession = (Request request, Response response) -> {
    // If the user is not set in the session
    if (!SessionUtil.hasSession(request)) {

        // Obtain the cookie session ID
        String sessionId = SessionUtil.getCookie(request);
        System.out.println(sessionId);
        // Obtain the user according to the session ID
        User user = app.getUserFromSession(sessionId);
        System.out.println(user != null);

        // if does exists we set the session
        if (user != null)
            SessionUtil.setSession(request, user);

    }
};


// Methods for the session
public static boolean hasSession(Request request) {
    if (request.session().attribute("user") == null)
        return false;

    return true;
}

public static String getCookie(Request request) {
    return request.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
}
public static void setSession(Request request, User user) {
        request.session().attribute("user", user);
    }
```

This is called when a login is succesfull. Cookie is stored in the user database persisting sessions

```
   public static void setSession(Response response, String cookie) {
        response.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, cookie);
    }
```

Comment: `response.cookie("my_cookie", "value");` is the way to go (don't know where you got the second method from). Maybe publish the route handler code too?

Comment: I have edited the post. Thank you.